# Installed pyocclient got AttributeError: module 'owncloud' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, django, pip, owncloud

I am trying to integrate owncloud in my django website using `pyocclient` package. I installed it using `pip install pyocclient` then I tried this example code from their documentation but got the error that owncloud has no attr `Client`

This is my code

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import owncloud

@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'home.html')
    else:
        f = request.POST['file'] # a txt file
        public_link = 'https://lblostenzexxx.owncloud.online/index.php/x/3'

        oc.login('uid', 'password')
        oc.mkdir('testdir')
        oc.put_file(f, 'localfile.txt')
        link_info = oc.share_file_with_link(f)
        print(link_info.get_link())
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'msg':"return"})
```

Below is console error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 30, 2021 - 03:30:14
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'owncloud.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[30/May/2021 03:30:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1084
[30/May/2021 03:30:14] "GET /static/css/login_signup.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2813
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mhashirhassan22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mhashirhassan22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mhashirhassan22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Work\Others\Upwork\owncloud\owncloud\users\views.py", line 13, in index
    oc = owncloud.Client.from_public_link(public_link)
AttributeError: module 'owncloud' has no attribute 'Client'
```

This is the github link for pyocclient https://github.com/owncloud/pyocclient

If there is any alternative to upload, share files on my django website without pyocclient, it can also help me. Thank you!

Comment: Do you perhaps have a file named `owncloud.py` or a package / directory named `owncloud` in your own code? If so rename it to something else.

Comment: not in my code, NO. It is in `pyocclient` package itself

Comment: Well the error seems to suggest `import owncloud` is not importing the correct package, check the output of `print(owncloud.__file__)`

Comment: You're right! My project's name was owncloud and it was importing its `__init__.py`  I changed the project's name and now correct package is imported. Thanks alot!!